# How to create a column in a data frame computed from another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following two data frames:

```
> df1
  col1
1    A
2    B
3    C

> df2
  col1 col2
1    A    1
2    A    2
3    B    1
4    C    1
4    C    2
4    B    3
4    C    3
4    C    4
```

Now I want to insert a new column `(col_max)` into `df1` with maximum values of `df2$col2` aggregated by `df1$col1`. So the required output is:

```
> df1
  col1 col_max
1    A    2
2    B    3
3    C    4
```

What I have tried (unsuccessfully) so far:

```
df1$col_max <- max(df2[df2$col1 == df1$col1, 2])
```

and:

```
get_max <- function(col_value){
    max(df2[df2$col1==col_value, 2])
}

df1$col_max <- get_max(df1$col1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get `max` value for each `col1` in `df2` and then `merge` with `df1`

```
merge(df1, aggregate(col2~col1, df2, max), by = 'col1')

#  col1 col2
#1    A    2
#2    B    3
#3    C    4
```

Using `dplyr`, that can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%  
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  summarise(col2 = max(col2)) %>%  
  right_join(df1, by = 'col1')
```

If all the `col1` values are present in `df2` no need to join we can just take max value by `col1`.